# ValueListenableBuilder : setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter

I couldn't find the answer in the other posts. I have the following error :

======== Exception caught by foundation library ====================================================
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for TextEditingController:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This ValueListenableBuilder widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: ValueListenableBuilder
state: _ValueListenableBuilderState#1deb8
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: TextFormFieldDefault
dirty
state: TextFormFieldDefaultState#0e026

I think this is coming from "ValueListenableBuilder", the error disappears if I delete it :

```
class UserAddAddressState extends State<UserAddAddress> {
  TextEditingController controllerName = TextEditingController();
  String autocompletePlace = "null";

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(defaultMainMargin),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                TitleDefault(content: "Adresse"),
                SizedBox(height: defaultMainMargin),
                TextFormFieldDefault(
                  label: "Name",
                  minLength: 1,
                  controller: controllerName,
                  initialValue: widget.getInformations["nameAddress"],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: defaultMainMargin),
                ButtonLikeFormFieldDefault(
                  onPressed: () => widget.selectAddress(controllerName.text),
                  content: widget.getInformations["address"],
                ),
                     ValueListenableBuilder(
                    valueListenable: controllerName,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, TextEditingValue value,
                        Widget? child) {
                      return Container();
                    
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you include your `MainButton`

Comment: I already tried this, and same error : 

```                ValueListenableBuilder(
                    valueListenable: controllerName,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, TextEditingValue value,
                        Widget? child) {
                      return Container();
                    }),````

Comment: Yes, I understood , but even removing it the error still exists, so it should not be taken into account.

Comment: Can you tell more about `TextFormFieldDefault`

Comment: It's just a classic TextButton with the same design as a FormField

Comment: I've simplified the code with  `ValueListenableBuilder` but failed to reproduce errors

Comment: I really don't understand why, sometimes it works, other times it doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248522/discussion-between-milaethe-and-yeasin-sheikh).